movie about a dog that runs away and has flashbacks
This was a live action film and the language was English. The location may have been England. It may have been a short film. I am sorry but I cannot recall when I saw it or it's release date.
Near the beginning of the movie authorities come to take the body of the deceased owner of a dog. The dog runs out while they have the door open. 
In another shows a shop keeper or pub owner tells someone that he had taken the dog home but his wife would not let him keep it so he had to set it free. 
The dog is on its own for a while, takes up with other strays, struggles to survive and often has flashbacks, of good memories, that look like still photographs. One in particular that I recall is of the dog remembering how the owner would always share his meager meals with it. The audience sees the old man reach down from the table to share his food with his furry companion. 
The dog finally decides to try to find its way back to its old neighborhood and in the process is rescued by a newlywed couple who knew his previous owner. They had been driving along and talking about how they wish they had known about the death of the owner and saying that they would have taken the dog. Just then they see it out on the road. They stop and get out of the car and call it by name. As it is running towards their out stretched arms a new snapshot appears in its mind which suggests to the audience that it will become a happy memory/flashback and that it will go with them to have a happy life.

Do you remember what kind of dog this was?
